# How can I select multiple components on selection of dropdown option in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to select multiple room components by choosing options from a dropdown menu and update the price accordingly. I attempted to add the rooms to a list when the dropdown changes, but it doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

This is my code from a separate room component file where I have dropdown widget.

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: ScreenUtils.horizontalSpace12!,
                vertical: ScreenUtils.verticalSpace12!),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Choose rooms",
                  style: textThemes(context).headlineMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: ScreenUtils.fontSize18!,
                        letterSpacing: -0.8,
                      ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: ScreenUtils.horizontalSpace8,
                ),
                CustomContainer.rectangle(
                  color: MyColors.dropdownColor,
                  borderColor: MyColors.greyDivider,
                  padding: 0,
                  radius: 4,
                  widget: Consumer<RoomProvider>(
                      builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: Dropdown(
                                hintText:
                                    "1 (NPR. ${roomlist.pricePerNight})",
                                selectedValue: value.selectedRoomNo,
                                optionList: value.roomNo
                                    .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "$e (NPR. ${calculatePrice(e)})",
                                          style: textThemes(context)
                                              .bodyLarge!
                                              .copyWith(
                                                  fontSize: ScreenUtils
                                                      .fontSize16),
                                        ),
                                        value: e))
                                    .toList(),
                                onchanged: onchanged)),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

And from this file I am calling the room component where logic for dropdown onchanged is written.

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        "Select your rooms",
        style: textThemes(context).displayMedium!.copyWith(
            fontSize: ScreenUtils.fontSize20!, letterSpacing: -0.8),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: ScreenUtils.verticalSpace16!,
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Consumer<RoomProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
            List<Rooms> rooms = value.roomList;

            return Wrap(
              spacing: ScreenUtils.horizontalSpace8!,
              children: [
                ...List.generate(rooms.length, (index) {
                  if (value.isLoading) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else {
                    if (rooms.isEmpty) {
                      return const Text("data");
                    }
                    if (index == rooms.length) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: ScreenUtils.horizontalSpace8,
                      );
                    }
                    return RoomComponent(
                      onchanged: (val) {
                        if (!rooms.contains(val)) {
                          roomsList.add(rooms[index]);
                        }

                        print(rooms);
                        print(rooms.length);

                        // value.changeRoomNo(val);
                        // var selected = val;
                        // // sel.insert(index, selected!);
                        // // print(sel);
                        // sel.add(rooms[index]);
                        // print(sel.length);
                        // var price = sel
                        //     .map((e) => e.pricePerNight)
                        //     .reduce((value, element) => value! + element!);
                        // print(price);
                        // (sel.map((e) => {e.pricePerNight!}));
                        // SelectedRoom selectedRoom = SelectedRoom();

                        // Provider.of<UIHelper>(context, listen: false)
                        //     .calculateTotal(price, int.parse(val!));
                      },
                      roomlist: value.roomList[index],
                    );
                  }
                })
              ],
            );
          })),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Please Post Code as Text don't post it image

Comment: If there is some UI element that needs to be updated, your widget needs to be a `StatefulWidget` and when you update, you need to use `setState(() {})`. It's lacking a bit of context so I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish.
If there's a UI element based on `roomsList`, do something like `setState(() {roomsList.add(val);})`